# Integrate a stubborn ISP router into an existing Unifi network

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, gateway, unifi

I have a Unifi USG router, Unifi switch and Unifi access point. I have 2 internal networks, 192.168.1.0/24 and 192.168.3.0/24.

I currently connect to the internet using an ADSL modem connected to the USG router's WAN port. It uses PPPoE.

FTTP has become available in my area so I jumped on the opportunity to upgrade from my current 4Mb/s.

The FTTP ISP supplies an all in one Nokia Wifi router which is not configurable. All the settings are locked except for the Wifi SSID and password. This routers internal IP address is 192.168.1.254/24.

How can I have my Unifi router send internet traffic to the Nokia router?

Comment: sounds like you will probably have to move your 192.168.1.0/24 network to another address range, or add another hop between the usg router and the isp router. sucks, I know. I do recommend avoiding low and high network ids in 192.168, as there is an increased likelihood of collision when using VPNs or inflexible ISP equipment.

Comment: Why not contact the ISP and have them reconfigure it for you?

Comment: I found a default user:password of AdminGPON:ALC#FGU gives full access and I changed the Nokia router's subnet. Behind triple NAT as the ISP implements CGNAT.